# Who does this statue represent?

Tags: identification-request

I recently inherited this little statuette, yet with my little knowledge of Hinduism, I don't know who it is.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statuette in your question which you want to know more about is of **Gautam Buddha** and the snake Mucalinda sheltering him.

[image]

You can read more about the above in this  [**Wikipedia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucalinda)   article.

Also there is   [**Buddhism Stack Exchange**](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions)  site  where you can ask questions about the above form of Buddha and about your statuette.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I wasn't sure which religion it was from. Should I flag/delete the question as off-topic then?

Comment: Hi , there is no need to delete the post as such. You can ask this same question on Buddhism Site for more comprehensive answer.